# Primary Key for new relations after 4NF decomposition

Tags: database, database-design, primary-key

Let's say I have a table `R` with attributes `A`, `B`, `C`, where `A` is primary key. Let's say I have multivalued dependency B->-> C. I decompose the table `R` into two new tables `R1` and `R2` where `R1` has attributes `A`, `B` and key `A` and `R2` has attributes `B`, `C`. What is the primary key for `R2`?

What I think the answer should be:
Since 4NF requires that every MVD's leftside should be a superkey then in the new table the key would be B, although the entire set of attributes could also be a superkey (albeit a trivial one but that doesn't matter in a 4NF decomposition, I think). So, that's my guess.

Based on the excellent advice of Catcall, the resulting R2 table would have many rows with duplicate values for B due to the multivalued dependency of B. The alternative options for keys are C by itself and B and C together. C can be a primary key if the C->B holds, which in this case it doesn't. Thus the only key in this situation is B,c. Can someone check if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Is this homework? If so then you should tag it as such. There are three possible keys for R2. Which do you think is implied by the MVD?

Comment: "So, that's my guess." Guessing doesn't scale well. Imagine what rows in R2 would look like.

Comment: "Thus the only key in this situation is B,c." That's right.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have:

A -> B

And

B ->-> C

This means that for every value of A there is only one value of B, and for every value of B there are many values of C.

After decomposition this makes (A, B) a superkey of R1 and (B, C) as a superkey of R2.

So the reasoning so far is right.  However, I don't think you can end there in the real world.  If you are designing a db, you also want to ask the following questions:

1. Is the following true?  C -> B  If so C will be your primary key, and (B, C) will be a superkey.
2. Is the following true?  C ->-> B  If so you have essentially a many-many join between two other entities.